# Using convert to create JPGs?

Tags: images, conversion, imagemagick, jpeg

When I use `convert image.png image.jpg` to convert a PNG to a JPEG, does `convert` perform any lossy compression? How much?

Comment: your choice when using `-quality` parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can define the amount of JPEG compression with `-quality`, e.g.

```
convert image.png -quality 100 image.jpg
```

Where `100` is no compression.  The default used by `convert` is `92`, which is a very common value in digital cameras.

There are several arguments on what amount of JPEG compression is a good amount and I am not planning to start another one.  I'll just point out that people most commonly use values between `95` and `75`.  The amount of filesize reduction by the amount of compression depends on the content of the file, therefore there is no magic rule.